# Query where id equals id of other column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a little project in C# WPF and entity framework 6

I need to make a query where the id of column ID in table1 equals id of column ID in table 2.

Anyone who can help me out?

Kind regards

```
Cursus cursus = DWE.Cursus.Where(x => x.Naam == CurNaam).First();
TbNaam.Text = CurNaam;
TbOmschrijving.Text = cursus.Omschrijving;
CmbSelBoot.SelectedValue = cursus.BootID;
TbPrijs.Text = cursus.Prijs.ToString();
//the following 2 lines should get the data from the new cursusweek table
BeginDate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Cursus.Begint);
Enddate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(cursus.Eindigt);
```

**database overview:**

[image: Database]

You can see i want to get data from Cursusweek. **I have got the id from Cursus and with that id i want to get the correct data from the Cursusweek table.**

Comment: Is there any foreign key association?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I will add some code to the start post with a database overview

Comment: And what is the data you want?

Comment: Added some of the code, with little explanation and a database overview. I want to get the "Begint" and "Eindigt" from the cursusweek table. So i have the table "Cursus" and the CursusID from that table has a relationship on the CursusID From "Cursusweek"

Answer (score 3):

This should be close to what you need:

```
var cursusWeek = Cursusweek
                     .Where(x => x.CursusId = cursus.CursusId)
                     .Select(x => new { Begint = x.Begint, Eindigt = x.Eindigt })
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, i Edited the line a little bit and it should work. It was very obvious:( sorry for this silly question The Final code:      Cursusweek cursusWeek = DWE.Cursusweeks.Where(x => x.CursusID == cursus.CursusID).FirstOrDefault();

'

Comment: Since the relation is `one-many` you should return a list instead of FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want, it can be the answer from Forklift or this one :

```
var v = cursus.Cursusweeks.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using(var db = YourDatabaseContext())
{
     var result = (from cw in db.Cursusweek
                  join c in db.Cursus on cw.CursusID equals c.CursusID
                  where c.CursusID = your_value
                  select cw).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and easy solution, would be hitting a new query over the ORM and take the information you need, for sample:

```
Cursus cursus = DWE.Cursus.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Naam == CurNaam);

if (cursus != null)
{
    TbNaam.Text = CurNaam;
    TbOmschrijving.Text = cursus.Omschrijving;
    CmbSelBoot.SelectedValue = cursus.BootID;
    TbPrijs.Text = cursus.Prijs.ToString();

    var cursusWeek = DWE.CursusWeeks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CursusId = cursus.CursusId);

    if (cursusWeek != null)
    {
        BeginDate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(cursusWeek.Begint);
        Enddate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(cursusWeek.Eindigt);
    }
}
```

The second option, and the best one, is to make a query to include the CrsusWeek object in the main query and use it from the `cursus` object. I am not sure about this option because I do not know your entire model. Given it is a one by one relation, could be:

```
Cursus cursus = DWE.Cursus.Include(x => x.CursusWeek).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Naam == CurNaam);

if (cursus != null)
{
    TbNaam.Text = CurNaam;
    TbOmschrijving.Text = cursus.Omschrijving;
    CmbSelBoot.SelectedValue = cursus.BootID;
    TbPrijs.Text = cursus.Prijs.ToString();

    var cursusWeek = cursus.CursusWeek;

    if (cursusWeek != null)
    {
        BeginDate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(cursusWeek.Begint);
        Enddate.SelectedDate = Utils.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(cursusWeek.Eindigt);
    }
}
else
{
   // show a message about Cursus not found here..
}
```

I also refactored your code. Use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid exceptions on empty results and give the right behaviour (messages).

Comment: If he return a list , he can easily check if the list is null or not. He doesn't have to use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I agree @Null, but from the perspective of the sample code on the question, he does not want multiple results.

Comment: Just in case , since the relation between those two tables is `one-many`